# Band Composite NetCDF file

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, netcdf, error-000732

I have multiple NetCDF files which were converted into tif files using the tools **Make NetCDF Raster Layer** & **Copy Raster** tool in ArcGIS Pro 2.6. As output, I now have multiple tif files with many bands inside it. Here is a screenshot for reference.

[image]

As I have multiple tif files of such kind, I am now trying to come up with a python script that can composite only certain bands.

So if the total number of bands in a tif file is 365 I only want to composite Band_167 to Band_193.

Here is the snippet that I have worked out so far however, it gives me an error : ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset Band_167 does not exist or is not supported

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Vikhyat\Test\*.tif'
Input = arcpy.env.workspace
Output = r'C:\Vikhyat\Data\Stack'

for img in Input:
    name = os.path.join(Output, img[0].split("_")[0] + ".tif")
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management('Band_167;Band_168;Band_169;Band_170', name)
print('Finished')
```

Comment: Your workspace should be set to r'C:\Vikhyat\Test'. May be try as the parameter for the input bands  "rastername.tif/Band_167; .....  rastername.tif/Band_193"

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for your input. As suggested, I only kept my workspace till folder name and then added raster file name as parameter and this time it gave me a very generic error message: ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.

Comment: Your for loop is wrong too, explore the help file on how to list datasets, in your case [ListRasters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/listrasters.htm).

Comment: @Hornbydd. Thank you for suggesting ListRasters method. It worked.

Comment: @Hornbydd As ListRasters worked I am back to my original problem in which I am not sure what to put in parameters of composite bands as if I put the "rastername.tif/Band_167....rastername.tif/Band_193" then it overwrites for all the tif files present in my workspace/folder and if I remove rastername.tif then I get an error of Band_167 does not exist or not supported.

Comment: I don't have your dataset, if you are willing to share it I/others could have a look?

Comment: Sure, please let me know how to share the data.

Comment: Stick it on your google/dropbox/one drive? Or use a file sharing website?

Comment: sure, will provide the link here.

Comment: @Hornbydd Here is the link to the drive which has the sample data as well as the python script that I have worked out so far. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IzfU27gA_zm4N0JYJafoXuYOKU1x30vC?usp=sharing . Thanks for taking your time out to look into this.

Comment: You can delete you upload, resolved, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you need is this, see how I build a list of full path to your raster\band.

```py
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Scratch\Test'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
Output = r'C:\Scratch\Test'
bandList = ['Band_167','Band_168','Band_169','Band_170']    
for raster in rasters:
    myList = list()
    print(raster)
    name = os.path.join(Output, 'Monsoon' + str(raster))
    print(name)
    for b in bandList:
        myList.append(arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + raster + "\\" + b)
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(myList, name)    
print('Finished')
```

It's good practise when developing code to put in print() statements so you can see what it is actually creating, for example your original code was creating `.tif.tif` as the output file name.

This tool did not seem to be honouring workspace so this is why I build the full path name.

Comment: Thank you so much @Hornbydd. This is what I was expecting to get as output.